# Using the new rtwn(4) driver for OpenBSD

Tags: wifi, openbsd

### EDIT 1: Patch from the mailing list

I got in touch with the original poster about the card, and he gave me a patch to try out. I will apply it, recompile the kernel, and report my findings. If it works, I'll change the status of this question to solved. Here it is if anyone is looking for it:

To patch:

```
cd /usr/src/sys/dev/pci
patch < /tmp/patch.txt
```

patch.txt:

```
 Index: if_rtwn.c
 ===================================================================
 RCS file: /cvs/src/sys/dev/pci/if_rtwn.c,v
 retrieving revision 1.1
 diff -u -p -r1.1 if_rtwn.c
 --- if_rtwn.c   4 Jun 2015 21:08:40 -0000       1.1
 +++ if_rtwn.c   4 Jun 2015 22:57:25 -0000
 @@ -80,7 +80,8 @@ int rtwn_debug = 0;
                     R92C_IMR_RXFOVW)

  static const struct pci_matchid rtwn_pci_devices[] = {
 -       { PCI_VENDOR_REALTEK,   PCI_PRODUCT_REALTEK_RT8188 }
 +       { PCI_VENDOR_REALTEK,   PCI_PRODUCT_REALTEK_RT8188 },
 +       { PCI_VENDOR_REALTEK,   PCI_PRODUCT_REALTEK_RTL8192CE }
  };

  int            rtwn_match(struct device *, void *, void *);
```

---

After spending two gruelling days trying to get FreeBSD to recognize my Realtek card, I decided to give OpenBSD a try. As of now, it seems to be the only BSD OS that supports the chipset of my `RTL8192CE` card. The `rtwn(4)` manpage says this driver supports devices based on the `8188CE` chipset (the one in this card). The problem here is that I'm using a snapshot, because this driver is new in 5.8, which isn't being released until October 18th.

I don't have access to another computer other than the desktop I'm working on, so I've been using my phone to research. I've only come across one thread on the mailing list archive that even mentions `rtwn`. A developer Stefan was asking if anyone had `(the card I have)` and wanted to test it with the driver, but the thread stopped there.

I have run `fw_update` locally on the rtwn firmware file I put on a thumb drive, so it should be recognizing my device. I rebooted twice after installing the firmware, but `dmesg` is still telling me that my device is unrecognized.

Is this a sign that my card simply isn't supported? Or does OpenBSD expect me to take care of some other configuration, process, or command before it will recognize my card?

This is the `dmesg` entry for my card:

```
"Realtek RTL8192CE" rev 0x01 at pci5 dev 0 function 0 not configured
```